# Is it possible to compile .NET byte code to machine language?

Tags: .net, compilation, clr, bytecode

Can you have .NET bytecode compiled straight into machine code?

I want to do this so I can increase execution speed. And I am talking about compiling the CLR bytecode only, and not direct source code compilation for C# or something. So, I can compile any .NET language to machine language by first compiling it to CLR bytecode, and after all the tests and prototyping is done, I can compile it to machine code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it seems possible (never tried myself), see the [C# Native Compiler](https://csnative.codeplex.com/) project, it aims to compile the MSIL to the native using C, this is how it works (as claimed from that page).

```cs
using System;

public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Assuming that you saved it as `helloworld.cs`, use the following command to compile it to native. (Requires MinGW32 installed)

```sh
Il2c.exe /exe helloworld.cs /corelib:CoreLib.dll
```

That should create a helloworld.exe file which is native.

Also there is an example project that uses C# to native compile an OpenGL application using this project, see it here - [Babylon 3D - C#/native port](http://babylon.codeplex.com/documentation).

Comment: @Switch We usually refer to compiled code that is ready to be executed as native code, which doesn't have any VM in the middle. CLR (also MONO) on the other hand has to JIT the MSIL bytecode.